# Command to run the app in a selected device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter

is there a command to run a flutter app in a selected device or platform? say, an android and ios emulator were both open. right now, `flutter run` will just run the app on the most recently opened device.

for example, in react-native cli, you can say `react-native run-ios` or `run-android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is `flutter run -d <deviceId>` and using `flutter devices` you can get the ids of the currently connected device available.